Spring - component-scan error while trying to use annotations
I am learning Spring, and following an example on YouTube about Annotations. When I try to use component-scan in the spring.xml file, I get this error message:

Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class
[org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser]
are only available on JDK 1.5  and higher

This is my spring.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
     <!-- <bean id="vehicle" class="com.spring.Bike"></bean> -->
 
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.Car"></context:component-scan> </beans>

I am using the latest Java version as follows:
java 23.0.1 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)

The editor is VSCode. How to fix this? I am unable to proceed.
My pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>first</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>first</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>23</java.version>
</properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.39</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>


Are you sure you are running your Spring application with JDK 23 and not with an older version that's installed as well? Which language level do you have defined in your Gradle/Maven files?

@knittl Do you want me to post the pom.xml for reference?

@BasilBourque Yes corrected the title. I am still getting around everything so I forget. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=If1Lw4pLLEo&ab_channel=Telusko

@BasilBourque Added the pom file.

You're new to Java, and you chose to start with an enterprise framework for building web applications?

Notice my corrections to your code formatting. Triple back-ticks go on their own line. And state the language.

@AbhijitSarkar Please avoid your personal opinions. Learning is for everyone, and I like learning languages with frameworks, makes it easier for me to learn. For example I learned Python with Django, because I come from a web background and that is what I can relate to better.

Your POM is mixing Java 8 with Java 23.

By the way, open-source support for Spring 5 ended. See documentation. Spring 6 is a major upgrade. Spring 6.2 is current. You may want to find a more recent tutorial.

@BasilBourque I have not edited it, only followed the tutorial, the config was generated by VSCode. Please can you help me fix it?I have been using VSC for many years now but I am starting to think I should stick to Eclipse/Netbeans for Java, faced too many issues in VSC. (Even though I call myself a noob, I have worked on Java 15 years ago).

@BasilBourque Ahh, I didn't know that. Let me find something newer.

I would not recommend VS Code as its support for Java is too new and limited. Oracle felt the need to introduce a different Java engine for VS Code to fill in shortcomings. With your ambitions, use one of the established IDEs: IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans.

Why do you have TWO Spring framework dependencies. One is specifying vesion 2.5 – version 3.2 has been end-of-lifed for almost ten years in 2016. Spring 2 was released in 2006 and Spring 3 in 2009. You want to at least use Spring 6.1, which is still maintained. All older versions will no longer receive any security or bug fixes.

Hey all of this config is generated by VSCode. Anyway, I have switched to NetBeans and made good progress since the posting of this question. VSCode has way too many issues. I was spending most of my time fixing those errors rather than focusing on my learning.

@BasilBourque Made the switch to Netbeans, immediately got productive. Thanks!

You have an error in your pom.xml file. This dependency is causing the problem.
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>

Remove this dependency from your pom.xml to resolve the issue.
Spring 2.5.6 does not support context:component-scan. This feature was introduced in Spring 2.5, but in a limited form. Full support for the @Component annotation and component scanning via context:component-scan appeared later, in Spring 3.0.
See article "New Features and Enhancements in Spring 3.0".

Thank you very much Andrey! I will mark this accepted. Although I didn't really try it, because I decided to follow a newer tutorial with the latest version of Spring, and switch to a proper Java IDE because VSCode has many issues.
